# NotifyDataSetChanged not working with Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using RecyclerView with Xamarin.Android. I'm filling the adapter with a `List<Article>`. For adding more items to list when user scrolls down I'm using `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener`. It triggers an even and inside the event handler I'm retrieving the data and adding it to the old list with and then call `adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged ();`. It retrieves the data and triggers the event but doesn't update the recyclerview on the device.

**What am I doing wrong??**

```
    RecyclerView recyclerview;
    NewsAdapter adapter;
    private List<Article> listofarticles;

        var onScrollListener = new XamarinRecyclerViewOnScrollListener (layoutmanager);
        onScrollListener.LoadMoreEvent += async (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
            //Load more stuff here
            Console.WriteLine ("*** loading more stuff ***");
            var newarticles = await GetData ("2");
            listofarticles = listofarticles.Concat (newarticles).ToList ();
            adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged ();
        };
```

Here's my adapter: (The clickhandler and itemcount methods are omitted)

```
// Adapter
    public class NewsAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
    {
        // Event handler for item clicks:
        public event EventHandler<int> ItemClick;
        private Context globalContext = null;

        // Underlying data set:
        public List<Article> _listofarticles;

        // Load the adapter with the data set (articles) at construction time:
        public NewsAdapter (List<Article> listofarticle, Context context)
        {
            this._listofarticles = listofarticle;
            globalContext = context;
        }

        // Create a new article CardView (invoked by the layout manager): 
        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            // Inflate the CardView for the photo:
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.From (parent.Context).Inflate (Resource.Layout.latestnews_recycler_article, parent, false);

            // Create a ViewHolder to find and hold these view references, and 
            // register OnClick with the view holder:
            NewsViewHolder vh = new NewsViewHolder (itemView, OnClick); 
            return vh;
        }

        // Fill in the contents of the article card (invoked by the layout manager):
        public override void OnBindViewHolder (RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            NewsViewHolder vh = holder as NewsViewHolder;

            // Set the ImageView and TextView in this ViewHolder's CardView 
            // from this position in the photo album:

            //vh.Thumbnail.SetImageResource (_listofarticles[position].Thumbnail);

            // We use Picasso to load images efficiently
            Picasso.With (globalContext).Load (_listofarticles[position].Thumbnail)
                //.Placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder) // optional
                //.Error(R.drawable.ic_error_fallback) // optional
                //.Resize(250, 200)                        // optional        
                //.Rotate(90)    // optional
                .Into (vh.Thumbnail);
            vh.Title.Text = _listofarticles[position].Title;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to add new items to the list **inside adapter** (not the one for the activity class) that is `_listofarticles` and then call NotifyDataSetChanged inside the adapter class like `this.NotifyDataSetChanged ();`. So to achieve that I added a method called `AddToList` to the adapter:

```
        public void AddToList(List<Article> newitemslist)
        {
            _listofarticles = _listofarticles.Concat (newitemslist).ToList ();
            this.NotifyDataSetChanged ();
        }
```

and I call it inside the event handler for scrolling like:

```
            var newarticles = await GetData ("2");
            adapter.AddToList (newarticles);
```

This properly updates the adapter and adds items to the end of recyclerview.

Answer (score 2):

In Xamarin because of memory management and garbage collection when using an ArrayAdapter, the implementation makes a copy of your backing list when you create it.

In order to be able to use the **NotifyDataSetChanged**, you need to use the Android.Runtime.JavaList instead of the .Net **IList**.

Here is a snippet :

```
ArrayAdapter adapter;
Android.Runtime.JavaList<string> messages = new Android.Runtime.JavaList<string>();
```

Then either on your **OnCreate** or in the **OnResume**, add the following code :

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, Android.Resource.Id.Text1, messages);
listView.Adapter = adapter;
```

You can now add items to your list and call the **NotifyDataSetChanged** and you should be able to get the changes.

In my case, i have a click handler on the button that updates the listview :

```
    void BtnSend_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var message = editText.Text;
        messages.Add(message);
        adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Been using .net's `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` since ICS/4/15, always seemed ok. Java specific code isn't portable to other platform targets.

Comment: Check the source code for the ArrayAdapter<T>, it makes a copy of your list, https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/master/src/Mono.Android/Android.Widget/ArrayAdapter.cs, if you want to still be able to add items to the list then you need a JavaList.

Comment: Mono.Android is the library used when targeting Android. Xamarin.iOS for iPhone https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios (thanks for link btw!). I guess in this case it's best to write platform specific code and port it? `NotifyDataSetChanged` works for me though, app is constantly adding, removing, and inserting to a .net List as user interacts.

Comment: I'm using a `ViewPager`, my bad.